# Null and 0 Values Handling - Basic Statistics

Tags: statistics, data-cleaning, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to do some descriptive statistics and basic graphs on relatively small data sets derived from environmental sample collection and/or chemical research. It turns out that sample points end up being recorded as a `0` if the analyte was not detected, or they are just left blank (`Null`) if a sample wasn't collected.

The problem is that this does not happen truly randomly, so I probably shouldn't delete any data. Also, there is no apparent predictability in the results, as environmental samples, for example, may not be collected for a number of reasons (inclement weather, equipment failure, etc.). I know that inferential statistics or modelling through ML is may be used here; however, I'm not well versed with these methods (and the data sets would probably be not large enough anyway, only a few dozen/hundred points). Is there is any generally accepted advice on possibly replacing the missing values or 0's with the population mean, or any other more basic statistical tricks like that? Otherwise, are there any cases in which excluding data points is acceptable?